How do i split set of data based on month and calculate duration between two date in google sheet?
I have set of data that have start datetime and end datetime, from this set of data I want to split the data in to two if the month of the two date is overlapping, then calculate duration based that month.
Example
start datetime - 1/15/2024 18:00:00
end datetime - 2/12/2024 14:00:00

If overlapping happened like the above, the duration will be calculate from the start datetime to end of the start datetime which is 1/31/2024 23:59:00, then the next month calculation will start from 2/1/2024 00:00:00 to the end datetime.
Example


Can this be done automatically using formula expressions, I already do it manually, splitting the data one by one then calculate the duration

Does google-sheets have functions like datedif() ?

@SolarMike yes.

will the split happen from year to year as in your image or month to month as in your question?

@player0 yes, it can be

try:
=INDEX(WRAPROWS(TOROW(SPLIT(LET(a,A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(, 0/(A:A<>""))), 
 b, OFFSET(a,,1), c, OFFSET(a,,2), MAP(a, b, c, LAMBDA(aa, bb, cc, LET(
 aaa, EOMONTH(bb, SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(bb, cc, "M")+1, -1))+1, 
 bbb, EOMONTH(bb, SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(bb, cc, "M")+1, )), 
 ccc, TOCOL(IF((aaa)>bb, aaa, bb), 1), 
 ddd, TOCOL(IF(bbb<=cc, bbb+"23:59:59", cc), 1), 
 TEXTJOIN(, 1, "×"&IFERROR(SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(bb, cc, "M")+1)/0, aa)&
 "×"&ccc&"×"&ddd&"×"&ddd-ccc))))), "×"), 1), 4))


update
=INDEX(WRAPROWS(TOROW(IFERROR(SPLIT(LET(
 a, RawData!E2:INDEX(RawData!E:E, MATCH(, 0/(RawData!E:E<>""))), 
 b, OFFSET(a,,1), c, OFFSET(a,,2), MAP(a, b, c, LAMBDA(aa, bb, cc, LET(
 aaa, EOMONTH(bb, SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(bb, cc, "M")+1, -1))+1, 
 bbb, EOMONTH(bb, SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(bb, cc, "M")+1, )), 
 ccc, TOCOL(IF((aaa)>bb, aaa, bb), 1), 
 ddd, TOCOL(IF(bbb<=cc, bbb+"23:59:59", cc), 1), 
 TEXTJOIN(, 1, "×"&IFERROR(SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(bb, cc, "M")+1)/0, 
 OFFSET(aa,,-4)&"×"&OFFSET(aa,,-3)&"×"&OFFSET(aa,,-2)&"×"&OFFSET(aa,,-1)&"×"&aa)&
 "×"&ccc&"×"&ddd&"×"&ddd-ccc))))), "×")), 1), 8))



for not closed ends you can use:
=INDEX(WRAPROWS(TOROW(IFERROR(SPLIT(LET(
 a, RawData!E2:INDEX(RawData!E:E, MATCH(, 0/(RawData!E:E<>""))), 
 b, OFFSET(a,,1), c, IF(OFFSET(a,,2)="", NOW(), OFFSET(a,,2)), 
 MAP(a, b, c, LAMBDA(aa, bb, cc, LET(
 aaa, EOMONTH(bb, SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(bb, cc, "M")+1, -1))+1, 
 bbb, EOMONTH(bb, SEQUENCE(1, DATEDIF(bb, cc, "M")+1, )), 
 ccc, TOCOL(IF((aaa)>bb, aaa, bb), 1), 
 ddd, TOCOL(IF(bbb<=cc, bbb+"23:59:59", cc), 1), 
 TEXTJOIN(, 1, "×"&IFERROR(SEQUENCE(DATEDIF(bb, cc, "M")+1)/0, 
 OFFSET(aa,,-4)&"×"&OFFSET(aa,,-3)&"×"&OFFSET(aa,,-2)&"×"&OFFSET(aa,,-1)&"×"&aa)&
 "×"&ccc&"×"&ddd&"×"&ddd-ccc))))), "×")), 1), 8))



It seem to be ok for the first three row, then it start to fail as my set of data is big. you can access my spreadsheet here, there are two tab RawData is my set of data, and result tab is what i want to achieve.
[link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19DL0bCXS_NMW-6CBhOtEWyRnPzKo9d4ijaIpcFUkx_4/edit?usp=sharing)

@MuhammadSyukriMansor can you point ot where it fails? just tested it in your sheet and works: https://i.sstatic.net/FeUt1jVo.png

Thanks ive test this formula and it also works..


Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Σ,tocol(,1),reduce(Σ,RawData!F2:index(RawData!F:F,match(,0/(RawData!F:F<>""))),lambda(a,c,let(Λ,if(offset(c,,1)="",now(),offset(c,,1)),Ξ,max(1,datedif(eomonth(c,-1)+1,eomonth(Λ,0),"m")),iferror(vstack(a,hstack(chooserows(offset(c,,-5,,5),sequence(if(eomonth(c,)=eomonth(Λ,),1,Ξ+1),1,1,0)), if(c="",,query(if(eomonth(c,)=eomonth(Λ,),hstack(c,Λ,Λ-c),
 byrow(wraprows(vstack(c,reduce(Σ,index(eomonth(c,sequence(Ξ,1,0))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,c+time(23,59,0),c+1))),Λ),2),lambda(x,hstack(index(x,,1),index(x,,2),index(x,,2)-index(x,,1)))))
,"format Col3 '[h]:mm:ss'")))))))))



It seems like whenever the end_date is blank, you are using the now() date+time which I've accommodated in the formula as well (from row 1582)



It seem to be ok for the first three row, then it start to fail as my set of data is big. you can access my spreadsheet here, there are two tab RawData is my set of data, and result tab is what i want to achieve.
[link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19DL0bCXS_NMW-6CBhOtEWyRnPzKo9d4ijaIpcFUkx_4/edit?usp=sharing)

Formula updated. Do a TRUE/FALSE check of the duration columns(expected vs formula output) so that you can get to see couple of mismatches...
